# z3: Modeling Java two's complement overflow and underflow in z3 bit vector addition

Tags: java, z3

I am trying to model Java 32bit int arithmetic. I am trying to use z3 bit vectors to achieve this. I am using the Z3 Java API from the unstable branch.

However, I do not know how to get the right overflow behaviour from z3. I want to model this behaviour:

```
0b01111111111111111111111111111111 + 1 == 0b10000000000000000000000000000000
Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

I can create a bit vector with the value `0b10000000000000000000000000000000` but when I use BitVecNum.getInt() I get an exception.

I run the following code:

```
((BitVecNum) 
   ctx.mkBVAdd(ctx.mkBV(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 32), ctx.mkBV(1, 32))
   .simplify()).getInt()
```

I get the exception `com.microsoft.z3.Z3Exception: Numeral is not an int`

If I do the following:

```
((int)((BitVecNum) 
    ctx.mkBVAdd(ctx.mkBV(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 32), ctx.mkBV(1, 32))
    .simplify()).getLong());
```

I get the result `-2147483648` that I want.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

This case is a little bit confusing, because Z3 treats all bit-vectors as unsigned, but the `getInt`/`getLong` functions look like they would return a signed value. What happens is that `MAX_VALUE+1` is correctly computed, resulting in 2147483648 (which is representable in a 32-bit unsigned int), but when getInt is called, it finds that this unsigned value does not fit into a signed int.

This problem stems from the fact that Java does not support unsigned basic types, so the corresponding Z3 functions (like `getUInt` and `getULong`) are not available in the Java API. My suggestion would be to always assume bit-vectors are unsigned in Z3 and to use wider datatypes (like the trick via `getLong`) to get around this issue. This is essentially also what other Java programmers do/suggest, e.g., [here](http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html) and [there](http://javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml).